# json object is not displaying on ajax requst in .net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i am sending a ajax request to a contrller to get some data.may be it working.but i cant use it in my project? dont know why ?means when i try to alert or use this data it not display .or even not giving me error message.

MAYBE THIS AJAX IS GOING TO DESTROY MY .NET INTEREST.

CONTROLLER CLASS/METHOD=>

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Getdata(string batchcode)
{
   var studentid = (from a in db.Studentassignbatches
                    where a.batch_code == batchcode
                    select new { a.UserId });
   return Json(studentid,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

AND MY VIEW CODE AND AJAX =>

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowBatchCode() {
    var batchcode = $('#BatchList').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '@Url.Action("Getdata", "Batche")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ batchcode: batchcode }),
        success: function (data) {
            var result = JSON.parse(data);
            result.forEach(function (obj) {
                alert(obj.UserId);
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Something Went Wrong!');
        }
   });
}
</script>
```

AND HTML=>

```
<select onchange="ShowBatchCode()" id="BatchList" class="form-control input-lg">
   <option class="pull-left" value="CCNA Security-1">CCNA Security-1</option>
   <option class="pull-left" value="CCNA Security-2">CCNA Security-2</option>
   <option class="pull-left" value="JNCSP-SEC-1">JNCSP-SEC-1</option>
   <option class="pull-left" value="Oracle Database 12c-1">Oracle Database 12c-1</option>
</select>
```

AND DATABASE=>

[image: DATABASE]
AND MY bROWSER INSPECTION RESULT=>

[image: bROWSER iNSPECTION]
HERE YOU CAN SEE THE ID IS COMING BUT WHY I CANT USE IT...
ANY SUGGESSION OR HELP????

Comment: can you do `console.log(data)` in success callback of ajax?

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: why do you use `JSON.parse(data)`? I think the data is already a JSON object. try `alert(data.UserId)` in the success callback.

Comment: alert(data.UserId) saying undefined!

Comment: you already have JSON object. so simply use the data. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Need to JSON parse as it is already JSON object

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowBatchCode() {
    var batchcode = $('#BatchList').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '@Url.Action("Getdata", "Batche")',
        data: JSON.stringify({ batchcode: batchcode }),
        success: function (data) {
            data.forEach(function (obj) {
                alert(obj.UserId);
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('Something Went Wrong!');
        }
   });
}
</script>
```